# How to print the title of the active window in C - WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi, hwnd

Well i have only one semester of C so i am little confused with `HWND` and how to use it. I just want to print active window.
I found - `GetActiveWindow`, `GetForegroundWindow`.

But i just dont understand how to use this function to print that active window.

I was trying to do something like.

```
HWND GetActiveWindow();
printf("%s", GetActiveWindow);
```

But that is probably bad use and not working.
If someone can gave me a working example i will be very thankfull.

Comment: What you expect to see - id (HWND) or window title (text)?

Comment: You lack basic C understanding. Calling a function requires (), e.g. GetActiveWindow() and it does not return a string, but a pointer. Better avoid WinAPI until you are ready.

Comment: @i486 Title of window.

Comment: @Michael Hmm yes. I know how to call function for example func1(param1,param2) but i am lost with this where to get string of windows title.

Comment: @Sheldon you need GetWindowText()

Comment: `GetWindowText( GetActiveWindow(), buf, sizeof buf / sizeof *buf )` where `buf` is `TCHAR` array. But `printf` means that you have console application and the title comes from Prompt (cmd.exe), usually "Command Prompt".

Comment: @i486 yes i just want to print active window in console.

Comment: @i486 And thank very much for code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TCHAR buf[256], out[280];

GetWindowText( GetActiveWindow(), buf, sizeof buf / sizeof *buf );
wsprintf( out, TEXT( "Window text: %s\n" ), buf );
```

Answer (score 3):

An `HWND` is a [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/handles-and-objects). It has an integral value, not a string value. If your intent is to print out the title of the window, you can first use the `GetWindowTextLengthW` to get the character length of the window title, allocate memory for it, then use the `GetWindowText` function to obtain a title from an `HWND`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sal.h>

BOOL PrintWindowTitle(_In_ HWND hWnd)
{
    INT nLen = GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd);
    WCHAR *wszTitle = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, (nLen + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));

    if(NULL == wszTitle)
    {
        SetLastError(ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY);
        return FALSE;
    }

    GetWindowTextW(hWnd, wszTitle, nLen);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", wszTitle);
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, wszTitle);

    SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);
    return TRUE;
}
```